# Does EGit mandate installing JGit?

Tags: git, eclipse-plugin, egit

After using Git from the command line for a while, I am ready for the convenience a GUI plugin (for Eclipse) can offer.

However, I prefer a Git plugin similar to to MS Visual Studio's `Git Source Control Provider` which is only a wrapper around the already installed [msysgit](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/5-windows-git-clients-git-job/). I really don't want two different Git implementations accessing the same repository.

EGit sounds perfect - if it can use the already installed [msysgit](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/5-windows-git-clients-git-job/) in my PC.

But can it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it can not. Egit as tooling part requires JGit as repository access part.

But there is really no problem using msysgit and Egit in parallel, that is what most users of Egit have done in the beginning (including myself), when EGit/JGit still lacked a lot of features. And JGit is also thoroughly tested, quite some bugs in the *native* git implementation have been found due to implementing JGit.

Comment: Thanks for an excellent answer. I believe the many people who say that so far there has never been an issue with using two different sets of code handling commit/checkout, but I'd rather play it safe. All it takes is a single unfortunate incident to lose work of years... This may not be the issue if I discover a problem as soon as it occurs, but if I blindly trust a system only to discover much later on that all my commits were corrupted in some way... I don't want my right-side of the brain telling my left-side *"I told you so!"*. :D

Answer (score 1):

jgit is a library that egit depends on, so jgit must be installed before egit can run.